# Call method in object passed to C++ from Haxe

Tags: haxe, openfl, hxcpp

I'm creating an OpenFL extension for a mobile advertising SDK, and I'm having difficulty figuring out some CFFI stuff.

Basically, I'm trying to pass a Haxe object to C++, and then call a method on that object from C++. The purpose of this is as an event listener, so when something happens in C++, I will call a callback on that object to notify the Haxe code.

I know how to do this with Java using lime's JNI stuff for Android. That looks something like this using [JNI type signatures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#type_signatures):

```
var setCallbackListener = JNI.createStaticMethod("com.test.myextension", "setCallbackListener", "(Lorg/haxe/lime/HaxeObject;)V");

var listener = new MyCallbackListener(); //implements `onSomething`

setCallbackListener(listener); //pass the listener to the Java side
```

Then from the Java side, I can call the function `onSomething` like this:

```
public static void setCallbackListener(HaxeObject listener){
    listener.call0("onSomething"); //call a function called "onSomething" with zero arguments
}
```

And that works, and it's how I'm doing it for Android. For iOS, I'm trying to do the same thing, but with hxcpp.

I know the general process for calling a C++ function from Haxe, using `cpp.Lib.load` in a similar way to the JNI api above. However, once I get a `value` type on the C++ side, I don't know how I can call a member function on it.

for example, say my C++ function looks like this:

```
#include <hx/CFFI.h>
static void setCallbackListener (value listener) {
    //...
}
DEFINE_PRIM (setCallbackListener, 1);
```

How would I then call the function "onSomething" in `listener`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging I figured it out! Unfortunately, none of this seems to be documented at all, so I figured I'd post my findings here in case someone else wants to do the same thing.

## Method 1

The hxcpp C API is apparently very similar to the Neko one, although not exactly the same. Still, the [Neko documentation](https://nekovm.org/doc/ffi/) is a good starting point.

That page shows you how to call a function by using `val_call0`, `val_call1`, etc. What it doesn't show you is how to obtain a reference to the function you want from an instance. To do that, you can use the functions `val_id` and `val_field` together like this (this is for hxcpp, not sure if it also works for Neko):

```
#include <hx/CFFI.h>
#include <hx/CFFIAPI.h>
static void setCallbackListener (value listener) {

    //get the field "id" from the name, which seems like a generic hash
    field fid = val_id("onSomething");

    //get the function from `listener`
    value myfunc = val_field(
        listener, //class instance allocated in haxe (type `value`)
        fid
    );

    //optionally verify that `myfunc` is 1) a function and 2) accepts 0 arguments
    //throws haxe error if this check fails
    val_check_function(myfunc, 0);

    //perform the call to `listener.onSomething()`
    val_call0(myfunc);
}
DEFINE_PRIM (setCallbackListener, 1);
```

If the function took 2 arguments instead of one (for example), then you'd use `val_call2`, and call it like this:

```
value arg1 = alloc_string("foo");
value arg2 = alloc_bool(true);
val_call2(myfunc, arg1, arg2); //arguments are of type `value`
```

There is also `val_callN` which accepts an arbitrary amount of arguments. See the [declaration here](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxcpp/blob/master/include/hx/CFFIAPI.h#L137).

Reference: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxcpp/blob/master/project/libs/std/Socket.cpp#L1039

## Method 2

Fortunately, there were only 3 results when I Googled "hxcpp val_call" (*without* quotes), and [one of those links detailed this method.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Haxelang/dlKAkSuZXSo)

Just read through that thread for a full explanation. That method would probably be preferred if you need better memory management, as it also shows how to tie in to the hxcpp GC from your C++.

#### Disclaimer

I couldn't find any actual documentation on `val_id` and `val_field`, so it's possible that these methods aren't meant to be used externally and might change in a later version of hxcpp. I have no idea. ‍♂️